# same chars different numbers

Tags: c, string, char

i recently started C again and i have a very very stupid problem i think, i bet it's just a very small mistake in my Code, but i can't find it (very embarassing i know...).

```
typedef char* String;

int contains(String string, String pattern);

int contains(String string, String pattern){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string)-strlen(pattern)+1; i++){
        printf("%d, %d\n", string[i], pattern[1]);
        if(string[i] == pattern[1]){
            printf("Found start... TODO");
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void){
    int z = contains("Heggo", "go");
    return 0;
}
```

Later the Code shall find substrings in a string, but thats to implement later (i have already implemented in java, it's easy), for now, i struggle with 1 problem: I print the actual letter in the string in a for loop and the first letter of the pattern string. but my output is:

72, 111

101, 111

103, 111

103, 111

so... WHY are the 'g's in the first string numeric values of 103, but the 'g' in the pattern string 111? it really bothers me because i bet it's just a really really stupid mistake from me..

Comment: Use `%c` to print char. `%d` is for printing `int`.

Comment: i know, thats not the problem, i want to know why there are different values for the same char

Comment: The conditional in your `for()`-loop is woefully wrong.

Comment: `pattern[1]` is the `o`.

Comment: the first letter is referred to with the zero index, not the one index. You are getting the value of `o`

Comment: why do you expect to by g and not o?

Answer (score 2):

Array indices start with zero in C. You want

```
    printf("%d, %d\n", string[i], pattern[0]);
    if(string[i] == pattern[0]){
        printf("Found start... TODO");
    }
```

The character at `pattern[1]` is "o":

```
>>> ord('o')
111
```